# Finding large primes

Tags: prime-numbers

I'm quite new to *Mathematica* and I am trying to find large prime numbers that can be written using only the digits 0, 1, 2 and 3 and more than half of these digits have to be 0. For example 1000 and 20001 would qualify.

I was thinking of using the `Prime[n]` function with a bunch if `If` statements, but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of going about this.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Is there any theory to help you find them?  A direct search is apt to be slow.

Comment: what do you consider large?

Comment: somewhere in the range of 10^12+

Comment: You need to use @george2079 to make sure the commenter is notified of your response.  Authors of posts are always notified.

Comment: Good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34695848/879601

Comment: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/114911

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For machine-sized primes (< 2^63 ~= 10^21), here's a simple compiled program to detect a good integer (digits < 4, mostly zeros).  You can leave off `CompilationTarget -> "C"` if you don't have a C compiler; it doesn't help much on my machine anyway.

```
good = Compile[{{p, _Integer}},
  Module[{n = p, q, r, z = 0, nz = 0},
   While[n > 0,
    q = Quotient[n, 10];
    r = n - 10*q;
    If[r > 3, Return[False]];
    If[r == 0, z++, nz++];
    n = q];
   Return[z > nz]],
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True,
  CompilationTarget -> "C" (* optional; helps only a little *)
  ]
```

Here's a basic use:

```
Pick[#, good@#] &@ ParallelMap[Prime, Range[1, 1000000]] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {1.01688,
   {100003, 200003, 1000003, 1000033, 1000303, 1001003, 
    1003001, 1003003, 1010003, 1020001, 2000003, 2000303, 2002001, 
    2020001, 2020003, 2100001, 2300003, 3000103, 3000301, 3001001, 
    3001003, 3002003, 3010001, 3200003, 3300001, 10000103, 10000303, 
    10003001, 10003003, 10030003}}
*)
```

The bottleneck is going to be `Prime` as far as speed goes.  `Prime` tries to be efficient.  It caches results and reuses them as starting points.

```
Quit[]
Prime[PrimePi[10^12]] // AbsoluteTiming
Prime[PrimePi[10^12]] // AbsoluteTiming
Prime[Range[#, # + 10] &@PrimePi[10^12]] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {1.62425, 999999999989}
  {0.005789, 999999999989}
  {0.003345,
   {999999999989, 1000000000039, 1000000000061, 1000000000063,
    1000000000091, 1000000000121, 1000000000163, 1000000000169, 
    1000000000177, 1000000000189, 1000000000193}}
*)
```

Notice the work that went into computing the first result.  When you parallelize `Prime`, it has to do all that work on each kernel.  But since it does it simultaneously, the user doesn't lose.  Note that computing each successive prime takes an appreciable amount of time, so this problem is a good candidate for parallelization.

Here is the timing in the neighborhood of the OP's interest.

```
Quit[]

(* Be sure to reevaluate the definition of good! *)

Pick[#, good@#] &@
  ParallelMap[Prime, Range[PrimePi[10^12], PrimePi[10^12] + 10^7]] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {85.3418,
   {1000000000121, 1000000000211, 1000000000303, 1000000000331,
    1000000000333, 1000000001123, 1000000001201, 1000000001213, 
    ... ~1000 primes omitted ..
    1000232020001, 1000233000001, 1000233000031, 1000233000101, 
    1000233000203, 1000233003001, 1000233010003}}
*)
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much.

Comment: @AlexanderMilanovic You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect it is faster to form digit-wise viable candidates, and cull the ones that are `PrimeQ`, than to iterate over explicit primes. The reason is that the percentage of the latter is going to be much smaller than that of the former, hence we can save considerably on the number of iterations and tests. The code below implements this approach.

```
Timing[Reap[For[j = 1, j < 10^5, j++,
    digits = IntegerDigits[FromDigits[IntegerDigits[j, 4]]];
    If[Last[digits] == 0 || Last[digits] == 2, Continue[]];
    If[Count[digits, 0] < Length[digits]/2, Continue[]];
    val = FromDigits[digits];
    If[PrimeQ[val], Sow[val]];
    ]][[2, 1]]]


(* Out[118]= {0.494928, {2003, 3001, 100003, 100103, 102001, 103001, 
  130003, 200003, 200023, 200033, 200201, 202001, 230003, 300023, 
  300301, 1000003, 1000033, 1000303, 1001003, 1003001, 1003003, 
  1010003, 1020001, 2000003, 2000303, 2002001, 2020001, 2020003, 
  2100001, 2300003, 3000103, 3000301, 3001001, 3001003, 3002003, 
  3010001, 3200003, 3300001, 10000103, 10000121, 10000223, 10000303, 
  10001203, 10002203, 10003001, 10003003, 10003031, 10010023, 
  10010101, 10012001, 10020013, 10020103, 10021001, 10021003, 
  10023001, 10030003, 10030103, 10033003, 10100011, 10100201, 
  10102003, 10200011, 10200101, 10200301, 10201001, 10203001, 
  10220003, 10300013, 10300201, 11002001, 11020001, 11020003, 
  11200001, 12001001, 12100003, 13000201, 13000301, 13000303, 
  13200001, 20000003, 20000023, 20000033, 20000213, 20000221, 
  20000303, 20000311, 20001001, 20001031, 20001203, 20001301, 
  20002201, 20003003, 20003023, 20003201, 20011001, 20020001, 
  20020103, 20020303, 20023001, 20030011, 20030203, 20100023, 
  20100203, 20101001, 20102003, 20130001, 20200013, 20203003, 
  20300003, 20300011, 20300101, 20300201, 20310001, 21000103, 
  21003001, 21030001, 21100003, 22000001, 22000003, 22000021, 
  22000031, 22000103, 22000201, 22010003, 22200001, 22300001, 
  23000011, 23000101, 23100001, 30000001, 30000023, 30000133, 
  30000301, 30000323, 30000331, 30001003, 30001031, 30001201, 
  30001303, 30002023, 30002033, 30002303, 30003101, 30003301, 
  30010021, 30010033, 30010103, 30010301, 30010303, 30013003, 
  30030023, 30030031, 30030101, 30100003, 30100201, 30100303, 
  30101003, 30103001, 30130003, 30200003, 30200011, 30200021, 
  30200033, 30200201, 30210001, 30300301, 30303001, 30310003, 
  31000003, 31000301, 31000303, 31002001, 31020001, 31030001, 
  32000011, 32000303, 32001001, 32010001, 32030003, 33000001, 
  33000031, 33000103, 100000123, 100000213, 100000223, 100000231, 
  100001203, 100001303, 100002011, 100002013, 100002031, 100002103, 
  100003021, 100003301, 100010021, 100010023, 100010033, 100010203, 
  100020023, 100020103, 100021003, 100022003, 100030001, 100031003, 
  100120003, 100130003, 100200011, 100200013, 100200031, 100200301, 
  100203001, 100210001, 100230001, 100300001, 100303003, 100310003, 
  100330001, 100330003, 101000023, 101000203, 101001001, 102000023, 
  102002003, 102100001, 102100003, 102300001, 103000201, 103000301, 
  103010003, 103300003, 110000201, 110002003, 110020003, 120000031, 
  120000103, 120000203, 120000301, 120001001, 120003001, 120100003}} *)
```

An iteration to 10^7 takes around 52 seconds and delivers 10151 such values (also 10501 is a prime, though not quite a contender; too bad it wasn't 10301).

Comment: Yeah, I get my 85-sec list, plus more, in 1.2 sec, with `Do[..., {j, 4^12 + 1, 4^12 + 4^9, 2}]` instead of `For` and skipping even numbers.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Originally I coded mod 3, where one cannot skip evens. When I realized mod 4 was required I failed to notice I could now skip the evens. Oh well.

Comment: Well, I dismissed your approach at first as infeasible because I didn't think of the `IntegerDigits[j, 4]]` trick. I hope people eventually recognize how superior this answer this.

Answer (score 3):

For example

```
pri = IntegerDigits /@ Table[Prime[n], {n, 20000, 90000}];

res = FromDigits /@ Select[pri, Count[#, 0] > Floor[Length[#]/2] && Max[#] < 4 &]
```

> {1000003, 1000033, 1000303, 1001003, 1003001, 1003003, 1010003,
>   1020001}

```
AllTrue[PrimeQ /@ res, TrueQ]
```

> True

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way to parallel compute the problem as only one Mathematica Kernel is used during the computation?

Comment: I found that using ParallelTable instead of Table in the first line seems to speed up the process

Answer (score 2):

The other answers here are satisfactory for your claimed range of interest, around $10^{12}$.  However, if you want *actually large* primes, I'd suggest a different method, using `NextPrime[]`.

```
random0123[length_, zeroFraction_] := Module[{
    numZeroes,
    startDigits, startNumber,
    rightDigits
  },
  numZeroes = Floor[zeroFraction*length];
  startDigits = Join[
    {RandomChoice[{1,2,3}]},
    Permute[Join[
        RandomChoice[{1,2,3},length-numZeroes-1],
        Table[0,{numZeroes}]
      ],
      RandomPermutation[SymmetricGroup[length-1]]
    ]
  ];
  startNumber = NextPrime[FromDigits[startDigits]];

  rightDigits[number_] := SubsetQ[{0,1,2,3},DeleteDuplicates[IntegerDigits[number,10]]];

  While[Not[rightDigits[startNumber]], 
    startNumber = NextPrime[startNumber];
  ];
  startNumber
]
```

This can generate somewhat larger results rather quickly, but the time can be highly variable.  (This variability is not clearly indicated below.)  If you're going to generate a lot of *large* primes, I'd come back to this and occasionally restart with a new set of `startDigits`.  (There don't seem to be any over here.  Let's try looking over there.)

```
RepeatedTiming[random0123[50,0.6]]
RepeatedTiming[random0123[100,0.6]]
RepeatedTiming[random0123[200,0.8]]
RepeatedTiming[random0123[200,0.2]]

(*  First number is average seconds, second number is the first prime it found.
  {0.02 , 10300220300000013020000000300110321000031302033231}
  {0.02 , 2000210102000000023103001031030300001000000203121000203000000120010020100320002300002001103230101021}
  {2.   , 30020300013030000021000000000003010002000030003003000000000000010000000000000033000033000100003000000000000000000030000100300000100000100030300000000000000000300200300000000000000101300120001000032103}
  {0.12 , 33220313233111203030200221002001211011010021331233310031111200312331021002103133323012223221232132101123113121023010111232133002002132222110213111312301013023313121301131322333131312121132021231203311}
*)
```

This function determines the number of desired `0`s and selects a uniformly randomly chosen, with replacement, collection of `1`s, `2`s, and `3`s to fill out to one fewer digit than requested.  (They're randomly ordered.  They don't need to be.  If we were going to generate a few million digits, we shouldn't randomize here; we should let the upcoming permutation do that work.)  Then a sequence of digits is constructed that is first, a random choice of nonzero digit, followed by a random permutation of the desired number of zeroes and the collection of nonzero digits just constructed.  Next we define a test function that verifies that a given number contains only the desired digits.  Finally we start searching from the generated number sequentially through the subsequent primes until we find one containing only the desired digits.

There are a number of obvious elaborations of this function:

- Specify number of zeroes instead of fraction of zeroes.
- Specify range of allowed digits or range of allowed number or fraction of zeroes.
- Specify how many results we want.
- Specify the leading digit to come from a different set of digits.
- Specify weights for the various digits.  (Perhaps `1`s are as likely as all other digits put together.)
- Supply specific counts ranges for each digit.
- Allow bases other than 10.
- Set a timeout for restarting the search from a new `startNumber`.
- Set an upper limit to the number of times to march on from a given `startNumber` before generating another one.
- Setup parallelization to simultaneously run multiple searches from different `startNumber`s.
- Keep statistics on number of times through the `While[]` loop and/or number of `startNumber`s used.
- Perhaps don't stop at the first valid prime in the `While[]` loop, but collect a sequence of successive valid primes, to get statistics on how frequent primes satisfying the given criteria are.

Comment: Actually the method I showed will handle ranges over large numbers just fine. The percentage of hits will drop of course, in accordance with the Prime Number Theorem. (If it is not in accordance with PNT, that would itself be extremely interesting, to say the least).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau : A difficulty with `PrimeQ[]` is that it caches results, but not its sieve between calls. (It expects random access over the integers.)  In contrast, `NextPrime[]` caches its "small primes" sieve so that subsequent calls can skip sieving.  (It expects sequential access over the integers.)  This may not show up in the above examples (10-200 digits), but I would expect to see a difference somewhere above 500 digits on recent hardware.

Comment: `Prime` uses a sieve. `PrimeQ`, which is the engine behind `NextPrime`, does not sieve anything. I'm not sure what you mean by a "small primes" sieve, but regardless I don't see an advantage to using `NexPrime` for this problem since it ends up doing just as many `PrimeQ` tests, if not more, than the method I had posted (and those are going to be a bottleneck).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau : Rather than argue...  The [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntegerAndNumberTheoreticalFunctions.html) states:  "`NextPrime[n]` finds the smallest prime $p$ such that $p>n$. For n less than 20 digits, the algorithm does a direct search using `PrimeQ` on the odd numbers greater than $n$. For $n$ with more than 20 digits, the algorithm builds a small sieve and first checks to see whether the candidate prime is divisible by a small prime before using `PrimeQ`. This seems to be slightly faster than a direct search."  So `NextPrime[]` for big primes.

Comment: (1) I should check that. I suspect it just means a `GCD` check is done with a product of several small primes before going to `PrimeQ`. It's been a few years since I've looked closely, but I don't recall anything really sievelike in there.

Comment: (2) I'm pretty sure that if a GCD or related test is done prior to invoking `PrimeQ`, the advantage will occur when one is finding multiple primes, that is, giving `NextPrime` a list a la "give me the first 10 primes after `n`".

Comment: I looked into the code and documentation on methodology. I guess it once worked that way, but not for the past several years. I filed a documentation bug report.

Answer (score 1):

construct random numbers meeting the critera and use primeQ.  This produces a handful of 2000 digit primes in about a minute.

```
len = 2000;
Union@Select[Table[
   nz = RandomInteger[{Ceiling[(len + 1)/2], len - 2}];
     FromDigits@
    Join[
     RandomChoice[{1, 2, 3}, 1],
     RandomSample[
      ConstantArray[0, nz]~Join~RandomChoice[{1, 2, 3}, len - nz - 2],
       len - 2],
     RandomChoice[{1, 3}, 1]], {2000}], PrimeQ]
```